# Loading Log4j.xml from outside fo the war

Tags: log4j

In my application iam using Log4j for logging.Presently I am placing log4j.xml in WEB-INF/classes. 
Below are the configurations i am using to load log4j.xml file.

```
<!-- language: xml -->

    <context-param>
          <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Now I need to place log4j.xml file outside of my war file. The location will be most likely JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy/settings. In settings directory i need to place my log4j.xml.

I tried to load it by setting jboss class path by editing run.bat as follows
set JBOSS_CLASSPATH=%RUN_CLASSPATH%;%JBOSS_HOME%\server\default\deploy\settings
and i used below in web.xml

```
<!-- language: xml -->

    <context-param>
            <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/log4j.xml</param-value>  
    </context-param>

    <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

But it throwing exception while deploying application. Exception is 
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid 'log4jConfigLocation' parameter: class path resource [/log4j.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist`

Now my question is how can I load it.

Comment: @atulkumar-v-jain your edit broke highlighting :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply declare location of log4j configuration like this:

```xml
<context-param>
      <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default/deploy/settings/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I don't want hard core location of lo4j.xml bcz whenver you want to change the location of it you have to modify it in web.xml and build war file

Comment: That's was just an example. You can use something like ${DEPLOY_SETTINGS}/log4j.xml

Comment: From where can i get this value. Do i have to set it as system property?

Comment: Either system property or environment variable.

Comment: the log4jConfigLocation is normally for within package customization. If it's from outside the package, it's better to use jboss global log4j configuration.

Comment: How to load logback.xml from outside folder, any idea?

Comment: Command line parameter ``-Dlog4j.config.location`` worked for me as well.

Answer (score 10):

Remember to add "file://" in front of the path, or else it will search inside the webapp folder.

The following example works for me.

```xml
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>file://${MY_ENV_VAR}log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: The javadoc for Log4JConfigListener says: "If you want to keep your WAR unexpanded or don't need application-specific log files within the WAR directory, don't use log4j setup within the application (thus, don't use Log4jConfigListener or Log4jConfigServlet)."  So why are you using this class?

Comment: I was able to get this to work when only there is one `/` after `file:` and not two.  I hope my advice helps others out there.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same exception.

I had used this code:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This exception disappeared when I executed:

> mvn clean install

Comment: Best part of this answer is classpath:log4j.properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- file:///${MY_ENV_VAR}/log4j.xml
- file:///${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default/deploy/settings/log4j.xml

Inside in your *log4jConfigLocation* tag.

Pay attention to add **file:///** if the path is absolute (outside the *webapp* folder)

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like this in the web.xml file:

```
    <context-param>
            <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>file://${JBOSS_HOME}/domain/configuration/log4j.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

  <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Note: for windows environment start with double "/" like "file://". For linux environment with sigle "/" like "file:/" .

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for [log4j2](/questions/tagged/log4j2) is a little different: uses `log4jConfiguration` param.
Refer to these answers:
[@rgoers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189928/load-log4j2-xml-file-outside-project-with-enviroment-variable) 
[@Gowtham](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257620/log4j2-configuration-file-found?rq=1)